# How to have a atm like numeric input onChangeText

Tags: react-native

How do I update the state?

```
onAmountChange = amount => {
    if (!amount || amount.match(/^\d{1,}(\.\d{0,8})?$/)) {
      const decimal = parseFloat(amount / 10 ** 8).toFixed(8);
      console.log(decimal);
      this.setState({ amount: decimal }); // will continue to be the first value
    }
  };



<Input
    keyboardType="number-pad"
    value={this.state.amount}
    onChangeText={this.onAmountChange}
```

Comment: Uncomment the `this.setState()` line and add `value={this.state.amount}` to the `<Input>`. If you do this, does it work? If it doesn't, what's the problem specifically?

Comment: Not working, the value remain the first amount

Comment: Does the `console.log()` before `this.setState()` log the new value correctly? Have you tried using `<TextInput>` instead of `<Input>`?

Comment: Have you made progress? Any updates?